# Change I2C baudrate on Android of Things with a pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, i2c, android-things

I'm trying to change the `baudrate` for `I2C1` on a raspberry pi 3 running android of things. I looked into the pio reference, but there doesn't seem to be any way to configure it through this:

https://developer.android.com/things/reference/com/google/android/things/pio/I2cDevice.html

I tried to follow the method to change the i2c clock on raspbian:

http://www.mindsensors.com/blog/how-to/change-i2c-speed-with-raspberry-pi

I found that there is a `"/sys/module/i2c_bcm2708/parameters/baudrate"` file, but this always reads "0" when I read it from the adb shell. I tried changing the config file `"root/CONFIG.txt"` on the sd card to include "dtparam=i2c_baudrate=500", "dtparam=i2c1_baudrate=500", and `"dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,i2c1_baudrate=500"` but this didn't change the `baudrate` file. I changed the frequency to 10 to see if it was working but not updating the file, but this didn't show any perceivable lag so I'm assuming it didn't work.

How do I change the I2C baudrate on Android of Things running with a pi 3?

Comment: The current I2C APIs do not support controlling the clock rate. There is an open feature request for this, which you can vote on and track: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65046298